# How do I filter for a specific word (map) then capture the next text up until the next space?

Tags: regex, excel, vba

I am trying to get the text right after - Map in this case example it is "AVE_NMHG_I_214_4010_XML_SAT" and input that into each Map Name row within the column up until the next space character found in could end up being "AVE_I_214_4010" as another example.

this is where I'm trying to make this fit.

```
Dim tmp As String
Dim RegX2 As Object, Mats1 As Object

tmp = strColS
Set RegX2 = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
With RegX2
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = "Map\d{7}"
    Set Mats1 = .Execute(tmp)
End With
If (RegX2.Test(tmp)) Then
   Set Mats1 = RegX2.Execute(tmp)
   tmp = Mats1(0)
Else
    With RegX2
      .Pattern = "MAP\d{9}"
      Set Mats1 = .Execute(tmp)
    End With
    If (RegX.Test(tmp)) Then
        tmp = Mats1(0)
    End If
End If
Set Mats1 = Nothing
Set RegX2 = Nothing
```

Note: there isn't always a Map specified and sometimes it is defined as MAP or map.

This code works by selecting the emails in outlook and then running the macro for only that selected emails.

This is an example of a subject that has the

Example Subject

```
RE: TS001889493 - Translation failure - Inbound - ( VEXP/ HONCE/ Document Type 214 - Map AVE_NMHG_I_214_4010_XML_SAT - Error Conditional Relationship Error in N103 (0066) [ ref:_00D50c9MW._5000z1J3cG8:ref ]
```

---

Example of body

```
Dear Valued Trading Partner,

We received the attached 214 transactions from Sender ID: VEXP/ Receiver ID: HONCE that failed due to Conditional Relationship Error in the N1_03 (0066).

As per the map logic, If either N103 or N104 is present, then the other is required as they are in conditional relationship with each other. But in the input file received, N104 value is missing hence the error.

Transaction Details: #4# Attached

Please correct and resend the data.

Thank you, Simon Huggs | Sass support - Basic
```

---

What happens in the #num# is that it gets the sum of all these after making a match of the "TS" ticket ID.

This is the code I have up until now

```
Option Explicit
Sub WritingTicketNumberAndfailuresnew()
 Dim xlApp As Object
 Dim xlWB As Object
 Dim xlSheet As Object
 Dim rCount, STicket, SticketNumber As Long
 Dim bXStarted As Boolean
 Dim enviro As String
 Dim strPath, SSubject As String

 Dim currentExplorer As Explorer
 Dim Selection As Selection
 Dim olItem As Outlook.MailItem
 Dim obj As Object
 Dim strColS, strColB, sassupport, sMailDateReceived, SFrom As String


 Dim Actions1, Actions2, Actions3, Actions4 As Boolean
 Dim I, cnt, email_needed As Integer

' Get Excel set up
     On Error Resume Next
     Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
     If Err <> 0 Then
         Application.StatusBar = "Please wait while Excel source is opened ... "
         Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
         bXStarted = True
     End If
     On Error GoTo 0

'Open a specific workbook to input the data the path of the workbook under the windows user account

     enviro = CStr(Environ("USERPROFILE"))
     strPath = enviro & "\Documents\topthreeticket.xlsx"
     Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(strPath)
     Set xlSheet = xlWB.Sheets("Sheet1")


' Add column names
  xlSheet.Range("A1") = "Email Subject"
  xlSheet.Range("B1") = "Map Name"
  xlSheet.Range("C1") = "Case Number"
  xlSheet.Range("D1") = "No. Of Failures"
  xlSheet.Range("E1") = "Date"
  xlSheet.Range("F1") = "Week Number"


sassupport = "sassuport@sass.com"


On Error Resume Next
'Find the next empty line of the worksheet
rCount = xlSheet.Range("A" & xlSheet.Rows.Count).End(-4162).Row
'needed for Exchange 2016. Remove if causing blank lines.
rCount = rCount + 1

' get the values from outlook
Set currentExplorer = Application.ActiveExplorer
Set Selection = currentExplorer.Selection
    For Each obj In Selection
    Set olItem = obj

'collect the fields for ticket number and failure count
    strColS = olItem.Subject
    strColB = olItem.Body
    SFrom = olItem.SenderEmailAddress
    sMailDateReceived = olItem.ReceivedTime

Dim sFailures, stmp1, stmp2, stmp3 As String
Dim RegX As Object, Mats As Object
Dim Found As Boolean

' Check the number of failures from body
   sFailures = "0"

   stmp1 = strColB
   Set RegX = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
   With RegX
       .Global = True
       .Pattern = "#\d+#"
       Set Mats = .Execute(stmp1)
   End With
   If (RegX.Test(stmp1)) Then
       stmp2 = Mats(0)
       Found = True
       stmp3 = Mid(stmp2, 2, Len(stmp2) - 2)
       sFailures = stmp3
    Else
       With RegX
          .Pattern = "#d\d+"
          Set Mats = .Execute(stmp1)
       End With
       If (RegX.Test(stmp1)) Then
           stmp2 = Mats(0)
           Found = True
           stmp3 = Mid(stmp2, 2, Len(stmp2) - 1)
           sFailures = stmp3
        End If
    End If

    Set Mats = Nothing
    Set RegX = Nothing

Dim tmp As String
Dim RegX2 As Object, Mats1 As Object

tmp = strColS
Set RegX2 = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
With RegX2
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = "Map\d{7}"
    Set Mats1 = .Execute(tmp)
End With
If (RegX2.Test(tmp)) Then
   Set Mats1 = RegX2.Execute(tmp)
   tmp = Mats1(0)
Else
    With RegX2
      .Pattern = "MAP\d{9}"
      Set Mats1 = .Execute(tmp)
    End With
    If (RegX.Test(tmp)) Then
        tmp = Mats1(0)
    End If
End If
Set Mats1 = Nothing
Set RegX2 = Nothing



Dim tempticketnum, tmpdate As String
Dim ticketnumposition As Integer
'write them in the excel sheet
If SFrom = sassupport Then
    xlSheet.Range("A" & rCount) = strColS
    xlSheet.Range("B" & rCount) = tmp2
    xlSheet.Range("C" & rCount) = tmp
    xlSheet.Range("D" & rCount) = sFailures ' number of failures
    xlSheet.Range("E" & rCount) = sMailDateReceived
    rCount = rCount + 1
End If
Next

     Set olItem = Nothing
     Set obj = Nothing
     Set currentExplorer = Nothing
     Set xlSheet = Nothing
     Set xlWB = Nothing
     Set xlApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

To extract the substring as you specify:

```
.ignorecase = True
.pattern = "map\s*(\S+)"
```

or

```
.pattern = "\bmap\s*(\S+)"
```

The substring will be in capturing group 1

If there is no `map` then the `.test(..)` line will return `False`

### Regex Explained

```
\bmap\s*(\S+)
```

Options: Case insensitive; ^$ don’t match at line breaks

- [Assert position at a word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) `\b`
- [Match the character string “map” literally](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) `map`
- [Match a single character that is a “whitespace character”](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\s*`

  - [Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `*`
- [Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 1](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) `(\S+)`

  - [Match a single character that is NOT a “whitespace character”](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\S+`

    - [Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `+`

Created with [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/)

Comment: Giving errors still 
 tmp2 = strColS
  Set RegX3 = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
  With RegX3
      .Global = True
      .ignorecase = True
      .Pattern = "map\s*(\S+)"
      Set Mats2 = .Execute(tmp2)
  End With
  If (RegX3.Test(tmp2)) Then
     Set Mats2 = RegX3.Execute(tmp2)
     tmp2 = Mats2(0)
  Else
      With RegX3
        .ignorecase = True
        .Pattern = "map\s*(\S+)"
        Set Mats2 = .Execute(tmp2)
      End With
      If (RegX3.Test(tmp2)) Then
        tmp2 = Mats2(0)
      End If
  End If
  Set Mats2 = Nothing
  Set RegX3 = Nothing

Comment: From your comment, I don't have a clue.  You did not mention in your question anything about an error.  What you asked for was a regex that would meet certain requirements.  The one I provided does that. If you have other problems, I suggest you ask a different question that clearly explains the problem.  Suggest you read the HELP pages for information as to [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help in formulating a good question.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was that it does find the map but if it does not it would give the full text rather than just leaving it blank since "map" was not added in the text.

Comment: I suggest you familiarize yourself with the regex object methods.  In particular, you are using the `.test` method which tells you if there is or is not a match.  You can then decide what you want to return based on that result.  It is straightforward Boolean logic.